# Summing up numbers based on the word using awk

Tags: regex, awk

There are multiple sentences lines, and they are in one of these outputs.

```
[%d][%d] msg_sent = %result

[%d][%d] msg_sent_node number = %result2
```

where %d, $result, and $result2 are numbers.

These lines are randomly ordered.

I want to sum up all the numbers that are in %result, and %result2 so it will print 2 numbers at the end (First one is sum of all numbers in %result, and second one is sum of all numbers in %result2 format.)

For example, if file consist of below 4 lines

```
[1][1] msg_sent = 5000
[1][2] msg_sent = 6000
[1][2] msg_sent_node number = 100
[1][1] msg_sent_node number = 200
```

I want 2 output numbers to be 11000, and 300.

How can I do that using awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/msg_sent_node number/ { node_total += $5  } /msg_sent / { sent_total = sent_total + $4} END { print sent_total " " node_total }'
```

which is probably easier to understand if written like so:

```
/msg_sent_node number/ { node_total += $5 } 
/msg_sent / { sent_total += $4} 
END { print sent_total " " node_total }
```

Comment: I think this is an amazing language.

Comment: `print sent_total, node_total` has the same output

Comment: Not everything has to be a regular expression: `$2=="msg_sent" {sent_total+=$4}`

Comment: `msg_sent_node number` will also match `/msg_sent/`, double counting...

Comment: I think you're right, good catch.  Added a space to disambiguate.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic and not-so-generic script to do this would be the following:

```
awk '{ if ($3 == "number") { b += $5 } else { a += $4 } } END { print a " " b }' file
```